# MongoDB net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED on server

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to make calls to my database from my react/node app hosted on a server. When run locally (using nodemon) the application is running at localhost:3000 and the server is hosted on port 4000, so I make api calls to localhost:4000. For example, `localhost:4000/students` displays the list of students stored in the MongoDB.

My server.js is as follows:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const PORT = 4000;
const cors = require('cors');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const studentRoute = require('./student.route');
const config = require('./secrets');

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.connect(config.dbUri, { useNewUrlParser: true }).then(
  () => {console.log('Database is connected') },
  err => { console.log('Can not connect to the database'+ err)}
);
```

I am deploying my application to my site by uploading the build folder that results from `npm run build` to a folder called 'the-wall' (the name of the project). So to access the application I go to example.com/the-wall.

My mongoDB is hosted using MongoDB atlas, and have whitelisted my IP address and what I believe to be the IP address of the server. I am making calls using axios, with the following config:

```
const env = process.env.NODE_ENV; 

export const app = axios.create({
  baseURL:
    env === 'production'
      ? 'https://example.com:4000/'
      : 'http://localhost:4000/',
});
```

However, when I try to access example.com:4000/student I receive a `net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` error. As far as I can tell, mongoDB is not installed on the server. Is the URL I am using incorrect, or is there additional set up I need to do?

Note: I have also tried example.com/the-wall:4000/student, but I get a 404 error with this one.

Does the way I am trying to make a call to the database look correct? (i.e. is the URL correct with the port, etc)

Comment: Try white-listing all IPs on Atlas to see if it's an IP problem. Also it's a good idea to add `mongoose.set('debug', true)` before you connect to help debugging. That way you can check the logs and have more details. If you have some logs of the error include them as an edit too

Comment: Whitelisted all IPs but nothing changed... I have a src folder (which contains app.js) and an api folder (which contains server.js). Locally, I run nodemon server from within the api folder. Do I have to do something to tell my server which file to look for? (I don't think the database connection is starting up on my server)

Answer (score 1):

Try to make it works locally with the production database.

If it works, it's an IP configuration problem on your server.

If it fails, it's a code configuration problem.

Comment: I believe it works with the production database. I am using mongodb srv connection (not mongodb://localhost:27017) and hosting it using nodemon. From here it works.

Comment: Does the way I am trying to make a call to the database look correct? (i.e. is the URL correct with the port, etc)

Comment: Well if you can connect the production database (like https://example.com:4000/) with your local server, the problem is not about mongo configuration. Could you connect your application production server with SSH and then, try to connect the database server, with telnet. The idea is to check there is no firewall

Comment: @MeghanKing What URL do you specify for it to work with a real MongoDB database? I have one and I can write to it, delete from it, etc... via methods in my `views.py` but I need to use the methods in my Angular service, which uses a url like `consumersMongodbApiUrl = "http://localhost:27017/consumers"`. Consumers is the name of my collection in the database. How should I change this url to actually connect to a real database?

Answer (score 0):

This usually occurs when there is a change in ip address.

check your connection on mongoDB, go to cluster and choose the project you're working on, navigate to network access and update your current ip address, right on top, find database access and update users by editing users to update it accordingly. check this `https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/troubleshoot-connection/`

This should work for you.